# Javascript - array of hash in a map function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have to return an array of hash in a map function like this:

```
results = [{title: "abc", category:"abcd", price: 23}, {title: "abc2", category:"abcd2", price: 24}]
```

I can do this in Ruby but I don't know how to do it in Javascript. I tried like below but I got a syntax error ": unexpected"

```
 const data = await page.content();
  let results = await page.$$eval(
      '.div',
      divs => divs.map((div, index) => {
        title: "abc",
        category: "abcd",
        price: 23
         }

      )
  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parens `()` around your braces `{}`:

This is valid:

```
let func = (div, index) => ({
        title: "abc",
        category: "abcd",
        price: 23
         })
```

This is invalid:

```
let func = (div, index) => {
        title: "abc",
        category: "abcd",
        price: 23
         }
```

The reason the parens are required is because otherwise, the curly braces would be interpreted as a code block instead of an object literal.